# Q: Using the vtable offset of a specific virtual function in a switch statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, constexpr, pointer-to-member, vtable

After reading (and hopefully learning) a lot about member function pointers, vtables, constexpr and its restrictions, unions etc. I've come to a point where I need help from the C++-experts:

I have to use a library with a lot of similar virtual methods. The methods may have different signatures, so that at least I have to provide a different set of call parameters for each method. In general, each method needs a different handling.

I try to use a switch statement to choose between the the different handling cases. The switch condition should be the methods offset in the vtable, which I assume to be

- unique for every method of the library and
- available at compile-time.

From other threads, where e.g. [strings are used as case-expressions](https://dev.krzaq.cc/post/switch-on-strings-with-c11), I learned, that to use the vtable offset as a case-expression, it must be a **constexpr**. Because of the many restrictions for **constexpr** I created a union to convert the member function pointer and provided a **constexpr** operator to return the unions value as an integer.

All this resulted in the following code, which is almost, but not quite, entirely unlike what I intended:

```
// Compiled with g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8~14.04.2) 4.8.5
// -std=c++03 and -std=c++1y give the same results !
#include <iostream>

// method library:
struct funcLib
{
    virtual void a() {}
    virtual void b(const double &_dVal) {}
    virtual void c(const double &_dVal, int &iVal) {}
};

// typedef to handle member function pointers with different signatures:
typedef void (funcLib::*T_Function)();

// union for type-conversion:
union funcID {
    T_Function m_funcPtr;
    uintptr_t  m_funcID;

    explicit constexpr funcID( T_Function _funcPtr ) : m_funcPtr(_funcPtr) {}
    constexpr operator uintptr_t() const { return m_funcID; }
};


int main()
{
    uintptr_t i = funcID((T_Function)&funcLib::a);
    uintptr_t j = funcID((T_Function)&funcLib::c);
    uintptr_t k = funcID((T_Function)&funcLib::b);

    std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << std::endl; // results "1 9 5" which seems to be OK!!

// Uncommenting the switch statement gives the error:
//  ../src/Test.cpp:37:44:   in constexpr expansion of 'funcID(&funcLib::a).funcID::operator uintptr_t()'
//  ../src/Test.cpp:37:44: error: accessing 'funcID::m_funcID' member instead of initialized 'funcID::m_funcPtr' member in constant expression
//
//    switch (i) {
//        case funcID((T_Function)&funcLib::a) : /* some handling */ break;
//        case funcID((T_Function)&funcLib::b) : /* some handling */ break;
//        case funcID((T_Function)&funcLib::c) : /* some handling */ break;
//    }

    return 0;
}
```

The first 3 lines indeed give me the vtable offset of the methods, which proves the type-conversion to be reasonable, but using the same calls in the case-expressions results in a compiler error.

Can somebody please have a look and give me some hints ?

**Addition:**
Here's some pseudo-code that hopefully clarifies my intentions:

```
// Own method to centralize the calls into the library
double T_MyClass::callLibraryMethod(T_FunctionID _funcID, T_CallParams _callParams) 
{
  double result;
  switch (_funcID) {
    case &Lib::methodA: result = Lib::methodA(_callParams); break;
    case &Lib::methodB: result = Lib::methodB(_callParams); break; 
    case &Lib::methodC: result = Lib::methodC(_callParams); break;
    ...
  }
  return result;
}

...

// Usage:

T_CallParams ParamsForMethodA, ParamsForMethodB;
double dResult;

...
dResult = callLibraryMethod(&Lib::methodA, ParamsForMethodA);
... 
dResult = callLibraryMethod(&Lib::methodB, ParamsForMethodB);
```

Comment: Note that using a union for type-punning (like you do) is technically undefined behavior.

Comment: You should be able to `static_cast<uintptr_t>` your values

Comment: The C++ language definition does not require a vtable; that's an implementation technique. Similarly, a pointer-to-member-function might be just a raw offset into the vtable, but it will typically contain more information than that. In general, don't try to use implementation details like vtables and representation of pointers-to-member-functions in your code. You'll end up getting yourself in trouble.

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve? You've shown code that doesn't work, but you haven't explained what it is that you're trying to accomplish. There are undoubtedly better tools available than hacking compiler-specific data structures. Maybe `std::function`?

Comment: Casting a member function pointer to a regular pointer is [not allowed](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#cant-cvt-memfnptr-to-voidptr). i.e. they are not representable by uintptr_t.

Comment: @Pete Becker: What I'm trying to achieve is to call arbitrary methods of a library in a similar manner from inside an own method, that takes the choosen library method and a structure of call parameters as arguments. Unfortunately, the library methods have no own unique identifier defined (i.e. a corresponding enum) that I can use for the switch condition / case expressions. So I had the hope, that I could somehow use the library methods "address", which, in my understanding, should also be unique and available at compile-time so it can be used as a case-expression (via constexpr).

Comment: @Caleth "`static_cast<uintptr_t>`" No sort of "pointer", not a pointer to member, not a true pointer, can be `static_cast` to any integer type. Only number types (integers, floats, enums) can be converted with a such cast to an integer.